# Crystal Reports, Cross Tab Report, Placing Headers Over Summary Data

Tags: crystal-reports-2011

I have produced a cross tab report in Crystal reports 2011 based on a SQL database.

Here is a screen shot
[image]

Now by default the cross tab report does not seem to give the summarised data any headers, so that my report shows 4 totals in each cell, but does not identify what each total is.  I have used a text box in an attempt to place some headers in the report as follows -

[image]

However, this does not solve the issue as the text box only appears in the first column, and not in subsequent columns, as the first picture shows.

Is there a way to add headers to summarised data in cross tab reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - there is an option on Right Clicking the summarised date, to include Labels, as per the following screenshot -

[image]